# array_map two callback functions as one

Tags: php, callback, array-map

Here is my codes:

```
$sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241 414844:412';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}/', $sc, $matches1);
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}:[0-9]{1,5}/', $sc, $matches2);

function cub1($match)
{

    return array(
      'batch' => $match,
      'type' => '1',
    );

}

function cub2($match)
{
    return array(
      'batch' => $match,
      'type' => '2',
    );
}

$pr_matches1 = array_map('cub1', $matches1[0]);
$pr_matches2 = array_map('cub2', $matches2[0]);

$all_matches = array_merge($pr_matches1,$pr_matches2);
```

It just works fine, i'm asking about if it possible to improve my codes and make the array_map callback functions (cub1 and cub2) as one function (cub), i just need to set different 'types' for $matches1 and $matches2

Any idea please?

Comment: This question would be clearer if we had the exact desired output as the final piece of the [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible, it's just a little bit tricky to identify in the function from which array it comes. But this should work for you:

(Here I just use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) to identify if it is a match form `$matches1` or from `$matches2`, since only the second array can contain `:`)

```
<?php

    $sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241 414844:412';
    preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}/', $sc, $matches1);
    preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}:[0-9]{1,5}/', $sc, $matches2);

    function cub($m) {

        if(strpos($m, ":") !== FALSE) {
            return array(
              'batch' => $m,
              'type' => '2',
            );
        } else {
            return array(
              'batch' => $m,
              'type' => '1',
            );
        }


    }

    $all_matches = array_map("cub", array_merge($matches1[0], $matches2[0]));
    print_r($all_matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [batch] => 8491241 [type] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [batch] => 6254841 [type] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [batch] => 568241 [type] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [batch] => 414844 [type] => 1 ) [4] => Array ( [batch] => 414844:412 [type] => 2 ) )
```

Comment: Rizier, Super observation sir.

Comment: Rizier, thank you, this going to work for my special case, but outside of that, is there is any solution can work with all?

Comment: @user2203703 No you would just have to identify the matches so that you can tell from which array it comes

Answer (score 3):

I'd simplify the whole thing to this:

```
$sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241 414844:412';
preg_match_all('/([0-9]{5,10})(:[0-9]{1,5})?/', $sc, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

$all_matches = array_reduce($matches, function (array $all, array $match) {
    $all[] = ['batch' => $match[1], 'type'  => '1'];
    if (isset($match[2])) {
        $all[] = ['batch' => $match[0], 'type' => '2'];
    }
    return $all;
}, []);
```

Use an optional capture group instead of two separate regexen, then distinguishing between both types of results becomes as simple as checking for the existence of the capture group.

Comment: Code of the question produces 5 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Some functional stuff

```
$sc = 'hello 8491241 some text 6254841 some text 568241 414844:412';
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}/', $sc, $matches1);
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{5,10}:[0-9]{1,5}/', $sc, $matches2);

$my_matches[1] = $matches1[0];
$my_matches[2] = $matches2[0];

$cub[1] = function($match)
    {
    return array(
        'batch' => $match,
        'type' => '1',
    );
    };

$cub[2] = function($match)
    {
    return array(
        'batch' => $match,
        'type' => '2',
    );
    };

$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array_map(function($a, $b)
        { return array_map($a, $b); }, $cub, $my_matches));
var_dump($result);
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/2ErJA)

So, you need two arrays of arbitrary (but the same) length: array of values, array of callbacks.